# Is my conception of set theory function composition correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to understand composition in set theory. My textbook gives:

> If $R$ and $S$ are binary relations on a set $U$ , i.e. $R \subseteq U^2$ and $S \subseteq U^2$, then the composition of $R$ and $S$, notation $R \circ S$, is the set of pairs $(x, y)$ such that there is some $z$ with $(x, z)\in R$ and $(z, y) \in S$. E.g., the composition of $\{(1, 2), (2, 3)\}$ and $\{(2, 4), (2, 5)\}$ is $\{(1, 4),(1, 5)\}$.

Wikipedia gives:

> $f = \{(1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 4), (4, 6)\}$
>
> $g = \{(1, 5), (2, 3), (3, 4),(4, 1), (5, 3), (6, 2)\}$
>
> then $g \circ f = \{(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 1), (4, 2)\}$.

This seems to me as pointer (or indexing) in programming where `1,3` from `f` refers to `3,4` in `g` and thus the composition of `g ∘ f` is `1,4`

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your understanding, but here is how it is to be understood:

First of all, what you see in the $\{(a_1,v_1), ..., (a_n,v_n)\}$ notation are the argument-value pairs of the function:

> $f = \{(1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 4), (4, 6)\}$

expresses the same as saying

> $f(1) = 3, f(2) = 1, f(3) = 4, f(4) = 6$

and

> $g = \{(1, 5), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 1), (5, 3), (6, 2)\}$

just means

> $g(1) = (5), g(2) = (3), g(3) = 4, g(4) = 1, g(5) = 3, g(6) = 2$

Function compostion $f \circ g$ now just means "First apply f, then wrap the result into an application of g". **$g \circ f(x)$ is the exact same thing as $g(f(x))$**, which is how it would be written in most programming languages. So

> $g \circ f (1) = g(f(1)) = g(3) = 4$
>   $g \circ f(2) = g(f(2)) = g(1) = 5$
>   $g \circ f(3) = g(f(3)) = g(4) = 1$
>   $g \circ f(4) = g(f(4)) = g(6) = 2$

You essentially chain the functions: **From $1$, $f$ takes us to $3$, and from there $g$ refers us to $4$, so chaining these pieces together we get $(1,4)$.** If this is how you understood it, then your understanding was correct.

Rewriting this in tuple notation -- taking the arguments $1, 2, 3, 4$ that $g \circ f$ is applied to as the first element and the reulting values $4,5,1,2$ as the second element of the tuples --, we get

> $g \circ f = \{(1,4), (2,5), (3,1), (4,2)\}$

as desired.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful as you explained the notation for " argument-value pairs of the function". I have one further thing that might improve your answer. How does this work when g = (1,5),(1,6)?

Comment: This can not happen, because then $g$ would not be a function at all. A function is *defined* as a relation where every argument (the element on the left) is assigned exactly one value (element on the right). So $\{(1,5), (1,6)\}$, where $1$ is assigned both $5$ and $6$, would simply not be a function, hence there the composition would not be defined either.

Comment: To be more precise, we *could* define composition on non-function relations, where we add *all* the tuples that have *some* (though not a unique) element as the middle step: $G \circ F = \{\langle x, y \rangle : \text{ for some y, } \langle x, y \rangle \in F \text{ and } \langle y, z \rangle \in G\}$. So if $g$ had both $(1,5)$ and $(1,6)$ in it, the composition $g \circ f$ would include both the pairs $(2,5)$ and $(2,6)$. But since it's not a funciton, we can lo longer write it in terms of $g \circ f(2) = ...$, since $=$ means there is exactly one value.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. Try this conception:

int f[] = {3,1,4,6};

int g[] = {5,3,4,1,3,2};

and then

cout << g[f[1]];

Answer (score 0):

You could see $f$ as a set of arrows on $U$, so $f=\{1\to 3,2\to 1, 3\to4, 4\to 6\}$, so draw a graph on vertices $1\ldots 6$ and label these arrows by $f$.

Similarly we can also draw (labelled by $g$) the arrows $1\to 5,2 \to 3,3\to 4,4\to 1,5 \to 3, 6\to 2$ and $g \circ f$ is then all arrows (i.e. pairs) that represent two-step paths that start with an arrow labelled $f$ and are followed by an arrow from $g$.

Your examples happen to be (partial) functions (for every $x$ there is at most one $(x,y)$ pair, but using arrows we can have several arrows coming from one point. Labelling and ordering (we start with the rightmost one, $f$) matter.